# How to solve npm "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am having issues with my `package.json` file.

It should work fine as as I use most of the node modules in other projects, but I have this `package.json` below:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
   "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
   "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
   "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
   "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
   "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
   "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
   "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
   "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
   "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^6.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.15"
  }
```

and they should all run fine as all dependencies exist as angular is now in rc.4 and rxjs is on 5.0.0-beta.10.

**But I get 3 unmet dependencies on**

```
npm install
'rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10'
'rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6'
'@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1'
```

I get these warnings too:

```
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
```

I have also done:

```
npm cache clean
npm update registry > with the registry link
npm update -g
```

node is on latest version and still same issue... so just wondering if there is something wrong?

Comment: remove everything, start installing rxjs first, then other packages

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly i will try that soon thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think its because the dependency resolution is a bit broken, see https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1341#issuecomment-20634338

You may need to manually install top-level modules that have unmet dependencies:

`npm install findup-sync@0.1.2`

Or structure your package.json such that any top-level modules that are also dependencies of other modules are listed lower down.

Your problem could also be that npm failed to download the package, timed-out or whatnot. Sometimes re-running `npm install` remedies it.

You can also install the failed packages manually as well using `npm install`

Other steps that may help before attempting npm install again are:

Removing node_modules using:

`rm -rf node_modules/`

then

`npm cache clean`

### To explain why removing node_modules sometimes is necessary:

Apparently if a nested module fails to install during npm install, subsequent npm install won't detect those missing nested dependencies. If that's the case, sometimes it's sufficient to remove the top-level dependency of those missing nested modules, and running npm install again.

See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1336